# SQL Server query slows down/has execution error with where-condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query takes about 40 seconds, sometimes even a execution error comes up:

```
SELECT        
    d.*, r.rights_PID AS freig_buha
FROM            
    dbo.V_Rechnungern_mit_freig AS d
INNER JOIN
    dbo.rights_buhauser AS r ON d.Re_Empfaenger = r.rights_FIRMENNR
WHERE        
    (d.freig_person = 18) AND
    (d.freig_erledigt = 0) AND 
    (d.max < 10) AND 
    (d.Belegart_N = 0) AND 
    (r.rights_PID = 40)
ORDER BY 
    freig_buha
```

After deleting this part:

```
 AND (r.rights_PID = 40)
```

It takes less than a second. If I change the part above to:

```
AND (r.rights_PID IS NOT NULL)
```

It takes 6 minutes. Reading other posts I have created this index:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex-20230124-102210] 
ON [dbo].[rights_buhauser] ([rights_PID] ASC, [rights_FIRMENNR] ASC)
   WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
         SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
         ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

This sadly made no difference.

To find the reason I put `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON` before the query, here is the result:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rk1-C7Tjj

Here the query definition for V_Rechnungern_mit_freig

```
SELECT        CASE WHEN V_Rechnungern_mit_freigbuha_poserl.INP_ID IS NULL THEN CASE WHEN freig_angefordert_von <> 16 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE 1 END AS buha_ok, 'freig' AS ursprung, 
                         d.Stapelname + N'-' + CAST(d.INP_ID AS varchar(2)) AS BUC_BUCHUNGID, dbo.web_Firmen.FIW_FIRMENNAME, dbo.web_Firmen.KUN_KundeBez, d.Re_Empfaenger, d.CRStatus, d.LiefenantenNo, d.Netto, 
                         d.Brutto, SUBSTRING(d.Text_Rechnungskopf, 1, 30) AS Text_Rechnungskopf, d.Rechnungsdatum, d.Rechnungsnummer, f.ID_freigabe, f.INP_ID, f.Stapelname, f.freig_person, 
                         CASE WHEN V_users.koppeln_mit IS NULL OR
                         V_users.koppeln_mit = 0 THEN freig_person ELSE V_users.koppeln_mit END AS freig_person2, f.freig_angefordert_wann, f.freig_angefordert_wie, f.freig_erledigt, f.freig_erledigt_wann, f.freig_abl_grund, 
                         f.freig_zahlsperre, f.freig_zahlsp_grund, f.freig_angefordert_von, dbo.V_users.Namen, CASE WHEN len(CAST(d .LiefenantenNo AS varchar(6)) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(d .Firmenname, 1, 30)) IS NULL 
                         THEN 'kein Lieferant gefunden' ELSE CAST(d .LiefenantenNo AS varchar(6)) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(d .Firmenname, 1, 30) END AS Lieferant, d.IBAN_ausgelesen, CASE WHEN d .Skontoproz IS NULL THEN NULL 
                         ELSE d .Skontoproz * 100 END AS Skontoproz, DATEDIFF(d, d.Rechnungsdatum, d.Nettotag) AS Nettotag, DATEDIFF(d, d.Rechnungsdatum, d.Skontotag) AS Skontotag, f.freig_erledigt_durch, d.bezahltKonto, 
                         dbo.web_Firmen.KUN_KORE, dbo.web_Firmen.KUN_Verrechn, d.pfad_original, d.pfad_win, 'X' AS fehlersuche, dbo.V_users.Mailanrede, dbo.V_users.email, dbo.V_Freigaben_ergebnis.max, 
                         dbo.V_Freigaben_ergebnis.min, CAST(d.Re_Empfaenger AS varchar(9)) AS empf_filter, d.Firmenname, d.pfad_webview, d.Belegart, d.Belegart_N, CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(d .Firmenname, 1, 20) IS NULL 
                         THEN 'Lieferant offen' ELSE SUBSTRING(d .Firmenname, 1, 20) END AS Lieferant_Name
FROM            dbo.freigabe AS f INNER JOIN
                         AuCl.dbo.V_Rechn_Header AS d ON f.Stapelname = d.Stapelname COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS AND f.INP_ID = d.INP_ID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.web_Firmen ON d.Re_Empfaenger = dbo.web_Firmen.FIR_FIRMENNR INNER JOIN
                         dbo.V_users ON f.freig_person = dbo.V_users.PID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.V_Freigaben_ergebnis ON d.INP_ID = dbo.V_Freigaben_ergebnis.INP_ID AND d.Stapelname = dbo.V_Freigaben_ergebnis.Stapelname COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.V_Rechnungern_mit_freigbuha_poserl ON d.INP_ID = dbo.V_Rechnungern_mit_freigbuha_poserl.INP_ID AND 
                         d.Stapelname = dbo.V_Rechnungern_mit_freigbuha_poserl.Stapelname COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
WHERE        (d.CRStatus <> 2)
```

view web_FIRMEN:

```
SELECT        fir.FIR_FIRMENNR, fiw.FIW_FIRMENNAME, fiw.FIW_MATCHCODE, k.KUN_Mailadresse, k.KUN_KundeBez, k.KUN_KORE, k.KUN_Verrechn, us.email, us.PID, fiw.FIW_FIRMAGUELTIGJAHR, 
                         k.KUN_Abgrenzungen
FROM            RZL.OFFICE.FIR_FIRMA AS fir INNER JOIN
                             (SELECT        FIW_FIRMENNAME, FIW_FIRMENZUSATZNAME, FIW_FIRMENZUSATZNAME1, FIW_MATCHCODE, FIW_FIRMENORT, FIW_FIRMENNR, FIW_FIRMAGUELTIGJAHR
                               FROM            RZL.OFFICE.FIW_FIRMENWERTE
                               WHERE        (FIW_ISTAKTUELL = 1)) AS fiw ON fir.FIR_FIRMENNR = fiw.FIW_FIRMENNR INNER JOIN
                         konto.dbo.STA_Kunden AS k ON fir.FIR_FIRMENNR = k.KUN_KundeNo LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.V_users AS us ON k.KUN_Bearbeiter_PID = us.PID
GROUP BY fir.FIR_FIRMENNR, fiw.FIW_FIRMENNAME, fiw.FIW_MATCHCODE, k.KUN_Mailadresse, k.KUN_KundeBez, k.KUN_KORE, k.KUN_Verrechn, us.email, us.PID, fiw.FIW_FIRMAGUELTIGJAHR, 
                         k.KUN_Abgrenzungen
HAVING        (fir.FIR_FIRMENNR > 100)
```

V_users:

```
SELECT        PID, firstName + ' ' + { fn UCASE(lastName) } AS Namen, lastName + ' ' + firstName + '; ' + email AS Namen_mail, company, koppeln_mit, Mailanrede, email, CASE WHEN koppeln_mit = 0 OR
                         koppeln_mit IS NULL THEN PID ELSE koppeln_mit END AS PID_gekoppelt, active, koppeln_mit_Rechten, tel
FROM            dbo.FREIG_users AS us
```

table STA_Kunden

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[STA_Kunden](
    [KUN_KundeNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [KUN_KundeBez] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [KUN_KundeBez_lang] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [KUN_Postfach] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [KUN_Mailadresse] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [KUN_KundeNoText] [varchar](6) NULL,
    [KUN_Bearbeiter] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [KUN_KORE] [bit] NULL,
    [KUN_Verrechn] [bit] NULL,
    [KUN_Abgrenzungen] [bit] NULL,
    [KUN_Bearbeiter_PID] [int] NULL,
    [KUN_RechnInfo] [bit] NULL,
    [KUN_AR_Rabatt] [bit] NULL,
    [KUN_AR_Jahr] [int] NULL,
    [KUN_AR_mailvon] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [KUN_AR_mailsubj] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [KUN_AR_mailbody] [varchar](5000) NULL,
    [KUN_AR_mailcc] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [KUN_AR_mailvon_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [KUN_AR_mailbcc] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [KUN_AR_mailantest] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [KUN_AR_mailsmtphost] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [KUN_AR_mailsmtpport] [tinyint] NULL,
    [KUN_AR_mailsmtpauth] [bit] NULL,
    [KUN_AR_mailsmtpusername] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [KUN_AR_mailsmtppassword] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [KUN_AR_maileigserv] [bit] NULL,
    [KUN_AR_mailreplyto] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_STA_Kunde] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [KUN_KundeNo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

V_Rechn_Header

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT d.Re_Empfaenger, d.Stapelname, d.INP_ID, d.LiefenantenNo, d.Firmenname AS Firmenname_autocl, lief.PER_NAME AS Firmenname, lief.PER_MATCHCODE, 
                         d.Netto * CASE WHEN Beleg_Gutschrift = 0 THEN 1 ELSE - 1 END AS Netto, d.Brutto * CASE WHEN Beleg_Gutschrift = 0 THEN 1 ELSE - 1 END AS Brutto, d.Text_Rechnungskopf, d.Rechnungsdatum, 
                         d.Rechnungsnummer, d.Lieferanten_Steuercode, d.Lieferanten_Gegenkonto, d.Lieferanten_Kostenstelle, d.Nettotag, d.Skontotag, d.Skontoproz, d.CRBemerkung, d.Lieferanten_IBAN, 
                         REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(d.IBAN_ausgelesen, ' ', ''), '-', ''), ',', ''), '.', '') AS IBAN_ausgelesen, d.SUB_ID, d.bezahltKonto, d.CRStatus, d.CRDocumentFile, 
                         '/mnt_AC_DATEN/savepic/' + SUBSTRING(d.Stapelname, 0, CHARINDEX('_', d.Stapelname)) + '/' + d.Stapelname + '/Doc/' + d.CRDocumentFile AS pfad_original, 
                         '/mnt_AC_DATEN/savepic/' + CAST(d.Re_Empfaenger AS varchar(9)) + '/' + d.Stapelname + '/' + Format(d.INP_ID, '00000') + '00001/webview.jpg' AS pfad_webview, d.Dateipfad, d.CRBilddateiName, 
                         '\\skuaucl\AC_DATEN\batch\' + SUBSTRING(d.Stapelname, 0, CHARINDEX('_', d.Stapelname)) + '\' + d.Stapelname + '\Doc\' + d.CRDocumentFile AS pfad_win, d.Buchungsdatum, d.Re_Auftrag, d.Re_KSt, 
                         d.Re_Steuercode, d.Re_Suchtext, d.Re_MWstProz, d.Re_MWstBetr * CASE WHEN Beleg_Gutschrift = 0 THEN 1 ELSE - 1 END AS Re_MWstBetr, d.Re_Konto, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('ar', Stapelname) 
                         <> 0 THEN CASE WHEN Beleg_Gutschrift = 0 THEN 'AR' ELSE 'AG' END ELSE CASE WHEN Beleg_Gutschrift = 0 THEN 'ER' ELSE 'EG' END END AS Belegart, 
                         CASE WHEN Beleg_Gutschrift = 0 THEN 1 ELSE - 1 END AS gutschr_multipl, d.Beleg_Gutschrift, d.Netto AS Netto_Orig, d.Brutto AS Brutto_Orig, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('ar', d .Stapelname) 
                         <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Belegart_N, d.abgrenzung_ab, d.abgrenzung_bis, format(CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN KUN_Abgrenzungen = 1 THEN abgrenzung_ab ELSE NULL END) IS NULL 
                         THEN Rechnungsdatum ELSE abgrenzung_ab END, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS abgrenzung_ab_anzeige, format(CASE WHEN CASE WHEN KUN_Abgrenzungen = 1 THEN abgrenzung_bis ELSE NULL END IS NULL 
                         THEN Rechnungsdatum ELSE abgrenzung_bis END, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS abgrenzung_bis_anzeige
FROM            dbo.DATEN AS d INNER JOIN
                         [szz].dbo.web_Firmen ON d.Re_Empfaenger = [szz].dbo.web_Firmen.FIR_FIRMENNR LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.dbo_RZL_V_Lieferantenstamm_lokal AS lief ON d.Re_Empfaenger = lief.PEK_FIRMENNR AND d.LiefenantenNo = lief.PEK_KONTONR
WHERE        (d.SUB_ID = 0) AND (d.CRStatus <> 0) AND (NOT (d.CRStatus IS NULL))
```

TABLE dbo_RZL_V_Lieferantenstamm_lokal

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dbo_RZL_V_Lieferantenstamm_lokal](
    [PER_FIRMENNR] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PEK_FIRMENNR] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PEK_FIBUNR] [int] NULL,
    [PEK_KONTONR] [decimal](10, 0) NULL,
    [lief_prim] [nvarchar](125) NULL,
    [PER_PERSONENID] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
    [KLI_KONDNR] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [PER_PERSONENART] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [PER_NAME] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PER_VORNAME] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PER_ZUSATZNAME] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PER_MATCHCODE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PER_UIDNR] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [PEK_KUN_MAHNSPERRE] [smallint] NULL,
    [PEK_KUN_MAHNDATUM] [datetime] NULL,
    [PEK_KUN_RECHNUNGSSPERRE] [smallint] NULL,
    [PEK_KUN_KONTENKREIS] [smallint] NULL,
    [PEK_LIE_KONTENKREIS] [smallint] NULL,
    [PEK_KUN_VORSCHLAGSKONTO] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PEK_LIE_VORSCHLAGSKONTO] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PEK_KLID] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
    [PEK_KLID_FIRMENNR] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PEK_KUN_ZESSKZ] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [PEK_GEGENVERR_KONTONR] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PEK_LIE_FREMDKONTONR] [nvarchar](35) NULL,
    [PEK_KUN_FREMDKONTONR] [nvarchar](35) NULL,
    [PEK_KUN_ZAHLSPERRE] [smallint] NULL,
    [PEK_KUN_MAHNSPERREBIS] [datetime] NULL,
    [PEK_KUN_ZAHLSPERREBIS] [datetime] NULL,
    [PEK_KUN_VERZUGSZSPERRE] [smallint] NULL,
    [PEK_LIE_ZAHLSPERRE] [smallint] NULL,
    [PEK_LIE_VERZUGSZSPERRE] [smallint] NULL,
    [PEK_LIE_ZAHLSPERREBIS] [datetime] NULL,
    [ADR_PLZ] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [ADR_ORT_LANDNR] [smallint] NULL,
    [ADR_ORTSNAME] [ntext] NULL,
    [ADR_STRASSE] [ntext] NULL,
    [WAEHRUNG] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [LAN_LANDBEZ] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [LAN_ISO_CODE] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [PER_SENDER_BANKINSTLFDNR] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PER_EMPF_BANKINSTLFDNR] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PER_FIRMA_BANKINSTLFDNR] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BAI_IBAN] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [KOD_ZZIEL_ALLG] [smallint] NULL,
    [KOD_SKONTOTAGE1_ALLG] [smallint] NULL,
    [KOD_SKONTOPROZENT1_ALLG] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [KOD_SKONTOTAGE2_ALLG] [smallint] NULL,
    [KOD_SKONTOPROZENT2_ALLG] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [KOD_KONDITIONBEZ_ALLG] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [KOD_KONDNR] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [KOD_ZZIEL_FIBU] [smallint] NULL,
    [KOD_SKONTOTAGE1_FIBU] [smallint] NULL,
    [KOD_SKONTOPROZENT1_FIBU] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [KOD_SKONTOTAGE2_FIBU] [smallint] NULL,
    [KOD_SKONTOPROZENT2_FIBU] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [KOD_KONDITIONBEZ_FIBU] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [KOD_ZZIEL] [smallint] NULL,
    [KOD_SKONTOTAGE1] [smallint] NULL,
    [KOD_SKONTOPROZENT1] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [KOD_SKONTOTAGE2] [smallint] NULL,
    [KOD_SKONTOPROZENT2] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [KOD_KONDITIONBEZ] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Table freigabe

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[freigabe](
        [ID_freigabe] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [INP_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Stapelname] [nvarchar](127) NOT NULL,
        [freig_person] [int] NOT NULL,
        [freig_angefordert_wann] [datetime] NULL,
        [freig_angefordert_wie] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [freig_erledigt] [smallint] NOT NULL,
        [freig_erledigt_wann] [datetime] NULL,
        [freig_erledigt_durch] [int] NULL,
        [freig_abl_grund] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [freig_zahlsperre] [bit] NULL,
        [freig_zahlsp_grund] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [freig_angefordert_von] [int] NULL,
        [mail_versand] [datetime] NULL,
        [vers_timestamp] [timestamp] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_freigabe] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID_freigabe] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    
    GO
    
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[freigabe] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_freigabe_freig_angefordert_wann]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [freig_angefordert_wann]
    GO
    
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[freigabe] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_freigabe_freig_erledigt]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [freig_erledigt]
    GO

view V_FREIGABEN_Ergebnis

    SELECT        INP_ID, Stapelname, MAX(freig_erledigt) AS max, MIN(freig_erledigt) AS min
    FROM            dbo.freigabe
    GROUP BY INP_ID, Stapelname

view V_Rechnungern_mit_freigbuha_poserl

    SELECT        f.INP_ID, f.Stapelname
    FROM            dbo.freigabe AS f INNER JOIN
                             AuCl.dbo.V_Rechn_Header AS r ON f.Stapelname = r.Stapelname COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS AND f.INP_ID = r.INP_ID
    WHERE        (f.freig_person = 18)
    GROUP BY f.INP_ID, f.Stapelname
    HAVING        (MIN(f.freig_erledigt) <> 0) AND (MAX(f.freig_erledigt) < 10)
```

table FREIG_users

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FREIG_users](
    [PID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [herr_frau] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [company] [int] NOT NULL,
    [email] [varchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [lastName] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [firstName] [varchar](26) NULL,
    [language] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [koppeln_mit_Rechten] [int] NULL,
    [koppeln_mit] [int] NULL,
    [groups] [text] NULL,
    [groupsAdm] [text] NULL,
    [passwordHash] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [pwdChangeToken] [varchar](160) NULL,
    [rights_maxbetrag] [float] NULL,
    [rights_vorgesetzter] [int] NULL,
    [rights_infoabbetrag] [float] NULL,
    [tel] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [mobile] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [comment] [text] NULL,
    [Mailanrede] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [short] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [department] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [street] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [city] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [zip] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [country] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [position] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [active] [tinyint] NULL,
    [lastchange_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [lastchange_user] [int] NULL,
    [option_pdfsep] [bit] NULL,
    [option_externoeffnen] [bit] NULL,
    [admin] [bit] NULL,
    [anmeldervers] [tinyint] NULL,
    [option_AR_pdfimmer] [tinyint] NULL,
    [option_AR_pdfextern] [bit] NULL,
    [option_ER_pdfbreite] [tinyint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FREIG_users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_FREIG_users] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [company] ASC,
    [email] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_FREIG_users_email] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [email] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FREIG_users] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_FREIG_users_passwordHash]  DEFAULT ('827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b') FOR [passwordHash]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FREIG_users] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_FREIG_users_pwdChangeToken]  DEFAULT ((12345)) FOR [pwdChangeToken]
GO
```

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Comment: Please use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ for the queryplan.

Comment: Also, don't post links to file sharing sites; the users here are far too aware of the dangers of downloading data from strangers on the internet. If the information is important, include it in the question. If it's an execution plan, use [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: thanks larnu, changed the tablse to read aliases, does not change speed. Still 37 seconds.

Comment: What is `V_Rechnungern_mit_freig`? A view? If that view is inefficient the query will be slow no matter what indexes are used in other tables. If the `freig_person`, `freig_erledigt`, `max` or `Belegart_N` fields aren't covered by indexes, or are calculated values, the server will have to scan all results of that query to find which ones match the criteria

Comment: I didn't say it would change the speed, @Max . That was not what that comment was about.

Comment: Without the view's definition we can't help at all. We need the view definition *and* the tables it uses. Indexing amount columns is rare, so I'd get `freig_person` etc aren't indexed. This means only `Belegart_N` and `rights_buhauser` could limit the results.

Comment: The order of columns in an index matters too. The most selective column (ie the one with the most values) should come first.

Comment: That plan shows ***a lot*** more than 2 objects, so we need to see that view's definition.

Comment: is there a "good" way to post the views definition? The veiw consists of two tables and 4 more views....

Comment: Yes, [edit] your question with the definition, @Max .

Comment: Also, nested views can perform *awfully*. Do those views, your view `V_Rechnungern_mit_freig` references, reference more views? If you are nesting views, we not only need the definition of `V_Rechnungern_mit_freig`, but also the views *it* references, and the view they reference, and... Honestly, I would probably start by getting rid of the nested views.

Comment: A view can be thought of as a macro; its definition is substituted into your code.  This means that you need to be aware which columns in the view are SARGable, and which are not.  That is why it becomes necessary to include view definitions in performance related questions (without understanding the view, it's often impossible to reliably diagnose the issues).  The same applies to the tables your query and views reference; we need to know which indexes exists (and do not exist) on all the tables referenced (whether through a view or directly).

Comment: Also, what precisely are you trying to achieve?  The initial query appears odd to me; `SELECT r.rights_PID` with `WHERE r.rights_PID = 40` implies that you're just checking if such a row exists, and so using `EXISTS()` may be advised.  But then you have two other variations; which is it that you're actually intending to use, and so needs optimising?  Similarly, `d LEFT OUTER JOIN r WHERE r.anything = anything` is going to cause the query to behave as an `INNER JOIN`, so why are you using an `OUTER JOIN`?  All  of this matters as, for example, your new index can not help in all scenarios.

Comment: MatBailie: the select was "shortened" to ease understanding, but I mocked it up - changed now! Also changed to inner-join. Actually changing to inner-join slows it down again (without where)